# Debug .NET Setup Project

Tags: .net, deployment, installation

How can I debug a .NET setup project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
Debugger.Break()
```

Comment: System.Diagnostic.Debugger.Break() - just in case

Comment: Just in case someone else stumbles here looking for this - it seems that in VS 2010 Debugger.Break() doesn't always work. If it's not working, try Debugger.Launch().